# Fake exception (ValueError)

Tags: python, exception, try-catch

My method is catching ValueEror, but it shouldn't occur in this situation. Input example: +15, -7.

What could be the problem and how to fix it?

```
def isdigit(number):
    try:
        int(number)
    except ValueError:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

[image] [image]

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error. `isdigit('+15')  # True`

Comment: do you want to raise fake error?

Comment: Check the indentation, I have edited in your question.

Comment: sorry i got now what you mean, this is really strange, iam having same bug :-)

Answer (score 0):

This approach is definitely what you look for

```
def is_digit(num):
  while True:
    try:
      num = int(input("Enter an integer number: "))
      break
    except ValueError:
      print("Invalid input. Please input integer only")  
      continue

print(is_digit("+9")
```

output

```
Invalid input. Please input integer only
```

upvote and check :-)